# Visualize sparsity pattern with intensity using Matlab spy function

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

Matlab has a function [spy](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spy.html) for visualizing sparsity patterns of graph adjacency matrices.

Unfortunately it does not display the points by taking into account the magnitude of the values in the matrix. It uses a single color with same intensity to display all entries.

I wish to display the same spy plot but with the points "color-coded" like in a heatmap to indicate the magnitude of the entries. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your matrix is not very large you could try to view it as an image using `imagesc()`. (Well you could use it for quite large matrices as well, but the pixels become very small.)

Here is an example of `20` random points in a `100x100` matrix, using colormap `hot`:

```
N = 100;
n = 20;

x = randi(N,1,n);
y = randi(N,1,n);
z = randi(N,1,n);

data = sparse(x,y,z);

imagesc(data)
axis square
colormap('hot')
```

This is the resulting image.

[image: Imagesc using colormap hot]

This can be compared to the plot we get using `spy(data)` where the markers are a bit larger.

[image: Reference figure using spy]

If a white background is desired an easy way to achieve this is to flip the colormap:

```
figure
imagesc(data)
axis square
cmap = flipud(colormap('hot'));
colormap(cmap)
```

[image: Imagesc using reversed colormap hot]

**Hack solution redefining spy()**

Googling a bit I found this thread at Matlab Central:

[Spy with color for values?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/7093)

There a solution is suggested that redefines `spy()`. It's however worth noting that (further down in the thread) this solution can also cause Matlab to crash for larger matrices.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It appears that spy gives a slightly different result... does it reorder the rows of the matrix or change it in any way? For e.g. there is a blue dot at the bottom right corner of your second plot that is missing in the first one. Or could it be that its value is so small that imagesc does not show it? This is not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @lightalchemist Yes, that is true, small values will easily blend with the background. You would probably want to use this as a complement to spy, to get a sense of the scale of the non-zero elements.

Comment: @lightalchemist The limits and scale of the colormap could probably be fiddled with to more clearly show also small values.

Comment: So it doesn't reorder the rows? On my computer, after thresholding all non-zero values to have the same value, the imagesc plot and the spy plot shows slightly different plots...

Comment: @lightalchemist No, it does not reorder rows. What differences are you seeing? I can not reproduce your problem. Could you add example data that gives you these problems?

Comment: it seems you are right. It is just that spy plot places markers which appears larger than what imagesc display on my monitor, hence giving the illusion that they are different. I marked yours as the answer instead of dlimpid's as it solved my problem first. However, I upvoted both answers as I feel they are both good answers in their own right. Anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

`spy` function uses `plot`, which cannot have different marker colors in a `lineseries` object.

On the other hand, `patch` object can have different marker colors for different vertices. `patch` is originally for drawing polygons, but with no face color and no edge color, one can get similar result to `plot` with no line style.

```
S = bucky();
[m, n] = size(S);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:m, 1:n);
S = (X + Y) .* S;

nonzeroInd = find(S);
[x, y] = ind2sub([m n], nonzeroInd);

figure();
hp = patch(x, y, S(nonzeroInd), ...
           'Marker', 's', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'flat', 'MarkerSize', 4, ...
           'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceColor', 'none');
set(gca, 'XLim', [0, n + 1], 'YLim', [0, m + 1], 'YDir', 'reverse', ...
    'PlotBoxAspectRatio', [n + 1, m + 1, 1]);

colorbar();
```

[image: Result with <code>jet</code>]

You can easily use different colormap, e.g., `colormap(flipud(hot))`.

[image: Result with reversed <code>hot</code>]

Comment: +1 Nice solution. The fact that `MarkerSize` can be set arbitrarily probably makes it more useful than my solution in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a file on matlab exchange that also performs the `spy` task with points colored according to their value. Please see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43183).